# Why DI is done at class Constructor in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I've been going through this one article on Angular services. And wondering why in general the instance of the service is created in the class constructor only?

For eg: - some **DemoService** class needs to be consumed in some **DemoComponent**. The instance of service will generally be created in the class constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
 ...
}
```

**DemoComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(
    private demoService: DemoService 
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

So, my **question** is, Can we instantiate the services inside `ngOnInit()` life-cycle hook method too?

Doing something like - or some other place maybe.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // using new DemoService();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you could, but then you wouldn't use DI anymore, so you'd have to pass every dependency to the service constructor by yourself, it wouldn't be an Angular service anymore (e.g. it wouldn't have the same scope, wouldn't be destroyed properly, etc.), it would make your code untestable, and you wouldn't be able to replace the implementation of the service by another one. Angular uses DI for many good reasons. You would lose all the advantages it brings.

Comment: Read this: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please explain more in detail in more simple language. Here it is   kinda confusing me.

Comment: *Why DI is done at class Constructor in Angular* Why not?

Comment: angular.io has several pages dedicated to DI. Read them. I won't regurgitate them here. DI is a common pattern, and its principle and advantages are heavily documented. Do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no this can't happen in `ngOnInit()`. Angular's DI mechanism needs to build the dependency tree of injected dependencies when it bootstraps. It needs to know

1. all objects it must create and
2. in which order it must create the objects and
3. all the injection points of the dependencies it is creating.

When we use Angular's DI we let Angular instantiate and manage the objects for us. We don't do it ourselves. This has the advantage of making the code very testable among other benefits.

The DI and object instantiation happens in the constructor because this is when the actual objects and the objects' dependencies are created.

In `ngOnInit()` all the objects in the dependency tree will have already have been built, so it's too late for dependency injection at this point.

However, it is possible to ask **Angular's** injector to give us an object it is managing (but again Angular has instantiated the object, not us). In some, usually rare cases, using the injector to get object instances may be needed. But usually, it is best to just let this all be handled during Angular's object tree construction bootstrap phase.

Comment: That makes sense to me :) Thanks for the detailed explaination

Comment: So, `@Inject()` inside constructor is similar to `private myService: MyService` and works in the same way.

Comment: yeah the `@Inject()` annotation will tap into Angular's DI framework and then in the constructor using keywords like `private`, `protected`, etc is a Typescript syntax that will turn the constructor parameters into class instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason that I can think of DI here is the `constructor` parameters of service (DI for service).
When you inject a service inside component using `DI`, you no more worry about service `constructor` parameters if any. Angular handles it by own.

For ex :

service

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
    constructor(myService : MyService){}
}
```

So when you have a service like above, if you are not using `DI`, then you care about `myService` parameter here.

For ex you will be doing

component

```
constructor(){
  let myService = new MyService();
  this.demoService = new DemoService(myService)
}
```

Its ok if you have written your own service.

What if you are using it from some library?? You have no idea what parameter to pass

Answer (score 1):

[**Dependency Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a Software Design Pattern which is used in many programming languages. Here's what Wikipedia has to say about it:

> In software engineering, dependency injection is a technique whereby one object (or static method) supplies the dependencies of another object. A dependency is an object that can be used (a service). Injection is the passing of dependency to a dependent object (a client) that would use it. Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to build or find the service, is the fundamental requirement of the pattern.

---

#### Following are the issues with a class creating instances of dependencies on its own and how Angular's DI Solves it:

1. It's **hard to maintain**. If a constructor of a dependency change, then we'll have to propagate the change to all the places in the code where that class was instantiated.

Consider this code, from [**DEPENDENCY INJECTION IN ANGULAR**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) - by Thoughtram, for eg:

```
class Car {
  constructor() {
    this.engine = new Engine();
    this.tires = Tires.getInstance();
    this.doors = app.get('doors');
  }
}
```

Here, since the Car class is creating the instances of its dependencies on its own, if tomorrow, say, the constructor of the `Engine` class was updated to require a `fuelType`, we'll have to pass that to the `Engine` constructor or our code won't work. Every time there's a change in the way a dependency is created, we'll have to make a change at every single place where we are creating an instance of that dependency.

**SOLUTION:** If we rely on Angular's Injector to provide those dependencies for us, this would look something like this:

```
class Car {
  constructor(engine, tires, doors) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.tires = tires;
    this.doors = doors;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `Car` class doesn't need to worry about changing anything in it as it doesn't have to worry about creating instances of it's dependencies.

2. It's **hard to unit-test**. As mentioned by [**Pascal**](https://twitter.com/PascalPrecht) in his [**article**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html):

> Just imagine you’d like to test this class. How would you replace Engine with a MockEngine dependency in that code? When writing tests, we want to test different scenarios that our code is used in, hence each scenario needs its own configuration. If we want to write testable code, we need to write reusable code. Our code should work in any environment as long as all dependencies are satisfied. Which brings us to the conclusion that **testable code is reusable code** and vise versa.

**SOLUTION:** If we use Angular's DI the code would look something like this:

```
var car = new Car(
  new MockEngine(),
  new MockTires(),
  new MockDoors()
);
```

See, how easy it would be to create a Mock of any of our dependencies.

3. It's **not a singleton**. All the dependencies created would be local to a class. So you won't be able to have a single service being shared across multiple class if you want to. Sharing of data would be hard to manage and it would make the whole setup, more and more complex. Watch [**"Why Dependency Injection"**](https://youtu.be/EzioZ9cww08?t=425) by [**kudvenkat**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCTVrRB5KpIiK6V2GGVsR1Q) to know more.

**SOLUTION:** If we rely on the Angular's Injector for these Dependencies, we can be sure that Angular's Injector is going to provide us with a Singleton, unless stated otherwise(in case you added service to the `providers` of a Component)

---

I'm again, linking a few resources that would be extremely helpful to you in understanding DI in Angular:

1. [**DEPENDENCY INJECTION IN ANGULAR**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html)
2. [**Angular dependency injection**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWODteEGQmw)
3. [**Why dependency injection**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzioZ9cww08)